# Python / Pandas - Filtering according to other dataframe's index

Tags: python, pandas

I have this two dataframes:

```
df1:
               Value
dude_id
123                x
543                y
984                z


df2:
          Value
id
123           R
498           S
543           D
984           X
009           Z
```

I want to filter `df2` in a way that it only contains the keys that are present in `df1`'s index.  It should look like this:

```
df2:
          Value
id
123           R
543           D
984           X
```

I tried the following:

```
df2.filter(like=df.index, axis=0)
```

However it is taking me to the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Int64Index is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `loc`

```
In [952]: df2.loc[df1.index]
Out[952]:
        Value
dude_id
123         R
543         D
984         X
```

And, you can rename the index name

```
In [956]: df2.loc[df1.index].rename_axis('id')
Out[956]:
    Value
id
123     R
543     D
984     X
```

Comment: df2.iloc[df1.index] did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you try the accepted answer but get an error like:

```
KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, 
see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'
```

Then instead try

```
df2.loc[df2.index.intersection(df1.index)]
```

Refer to Pandas documentation on [reindexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#reindexing).